# oracle Jdbc update statement return zero

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

This is regarding sql update statement using JDBC. Actually I'm looking into some issue we had, which all come to hang at a point where update statement has returned zero while trying to update certain row.

Now to make it clear,THE SPECIFIC ROW UPDATE STATEMENT IS TRYING TO UPDATE DO EXIST in the table.So there is no possibility of record not found and hence zero update.

Having mentioned that, my question is, do you see or is their any other possibility where zero can be returned by the update. I'm using oracle jdbc driver. so do oracle jdbc mention any scenario where zero can be returned by the update statement other than record not found.

Many thanks,
Ameer Mawia

Comment: "So there is no possibility of record not found" - that's typically what's said *just* before, "Ah, *that's* why the record isn't being found..." Please show some code.

Comment: I'm under server constrain not to share the code, though I can say that it is pretty mundane, getting a connection, creating prepared statement and executing it. Hope you appreciate this constrain I have to respect to.

Comment: Not really, because you're providing no indication of how you've checked that it *really* finds a row. For example, if you change the `UPDATE` to a `SELECT` and remove the new values (but otherwise don't touch the query) do you *then* see it working? In my experience it's likely to be a typo which is as mundane as the query...

Comment: Beating a dead horse (Question is two years old) but I just experienced this and found a possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543016

Answer (score 0):

executeUpdate

int executeUpdate()
                  throws SQLException

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Returns:
        either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing 
    Throws:
   SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object

Just to say that the doc specifies:

"Note that when the return value for executeUpdate is 0, it can mean one of two things:

The statement executed was an update statement that affected zero rows.
   The statement executed was a DDL statement."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know how to post a comment yet, so...

From Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Note that when the return value for executeUpdate is 0, it can mean one of two things:

```
* The statement executed was an update statement that affected zero rows.
* The statement executed was a DDL statement.
```

So it would seem the Update statement might be getting mangled in some way you didn't expect. I would think this was the case considering an Exception wasn't thrown.  If this is repeatable, you should be able to monitor the SQL that was sent on the server side and see what your missing.