# Why is my JDBC update not working?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've been migrating from PostgreSQL 9.1 to Oracle 11gR2 and have run into an odd issue.

I've been running code that updates a table when a customer has been added to our ERP system. This code has been running on PostgreSQL with no issues since March. Now that I'm switching to  Oracle the same code is no longer updating.

**Original Code**

```
update = "UPDATE store SET added_customer = 'y' WHERE order_id = ?";
try {
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
    pStmnt.setString(1, orderId);               
    results = pStmnt.executeUpdate();

    if (results > 0) {
        added = true;                   
    }       
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
}
```

No exceptions were thrown, but no data changed so I thought "autocommit must not be working, lets commit manually":

**New Code**

```
update = "UPDATE shop_ca_orders SET added_customer = 'y' WHERE order_id = ?";
try {                 
    getConn().setAutoCommit(false); //Added
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
    pStmnt.setString(1, orderId);               
    results = pStmnt.executeUpdate();

    if (results > 0) {
        added = true;
        getConn().commit(); //Added
        getConn().setAutoCommit(true); //Added
    }       
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
}
```

Still no luck so I added `LOGGER.debug("Update to order returned {}",results);` after the `executeUpdate` statement and found I am returning 0, so no records are being updated.

Interesting, so I tried the query via SQL Developer and it updated correctly.  This brings me to my question:

**Why am I unable to update my database via JDBC?**

**Essential Data:**

- `order_id` is type `VARCHAR(255 BYTE)`.
- Java 7
- Oracle 11GR2 running on Amazons RDS
- Migrated from PostgreSQL 9.1 running on Heroku
- On PostgreSQL `order_id` is a `character varying(255)`

**EDIT**

A small schema change was undetected and resulted in a bug where the order ID was actually the name of the person, and not the order ID. Bonehead error on my end. Anyways, now that I have that resolved and pulling the correct order ID I have found that I am hanging on `executeUpdate`. Currently working on that issue. I'll likely create a new question if I am unable to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

What does `getConn()` return ? I suspect it's a different (pooled?) connection each time.

This:

```
getConn().setAutoCommit(false); //Added
PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
```

should likely read:

```
Connection c = getConn();
c.setAutoCommit(false); //Added
PreparedStatement pStmnt = c.prepareStatement(update);
```

i.e. if `getConn()` returns a different connection each time, then you've got problems.

Comment: I've never considered that, let me give it a spin

Comment: Still returning 0 for the update. getConn() returns the connection object created in the class constructor. No pooling is used.

Comment: Even though this isn't a direct answer, it pointed me to what I needed to investigate to find that answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So my issue was two fold:

First I had an issue with my initial result set. During the migration one column was removed, I thought all the referenced columns were changed in code, however one was missing. Once this issue was resolved the order ID worked accurately and it attempted to update the database.

The second issue was a problem with the database hanging on the update. It turns out that the hang was caused by SQL Developer holding a lock on the database (or table, not sure which) - once I closed SQL Developer the update immediately completed and things went as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this issue a few years ago, and when I used a String value on a WHERE clause, using tokens, it didn't worked. BTW, it was also an Oracle database (10g)

Finally, I gave up, and changed the code to concatenate the value instead of tokenize it

From

```
update = "UPDATE shop_ca_orders SET added_customer = 'y' WHERE order_id = ?";
try {                 
    getConn().setAutoCommit(false); //Added
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
    pStmnt.setString(1, orderId);               
    results = pStmnt.executeUpdate();

    if (results > 0) {
        added = true;
        getConn().commit(); //Added
        getConn().setAutoCommit(true); //Added
    }       
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
}
```

To

```
update = "UPDATE shop_ca_orders SET added_customer = 'y' WHERE order_id = ' + order_id + '";
try {                 
    getConn().setAutoCommit(false); //Added
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
    results = pStmnt.executeUpdate();

    if (results > 0) {
        added = true;
        getConn().commit(); //Added
        getConn().setAutoCommit(true); //Added
    }       
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
}
```

That did the trick for me... This is not the most elegant solution, but is a workaround

====================== UPDATE 1 ============================

I've done a little more research, since I also faced this problem and still didn't get a valid answer

Looks like Oracle drivers expects you to pass a String with similar length to the table definition. This happens only to fixed length columns (like CHAR), VARCHAR columns doesn't seem to be affected by this.

It means that, if `order_id` is a CHAR(10) , then you should pad your String to complete the column  length. A better approach would be to trim the database value to match the token value.

```
update = "UPDATE shop_ca_orders SET added_customer = 'y' " + 
         " WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(order_id)) = ?";
try {                 
    getConn().setAutoCommit(false); //Added
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = getConn().prepareStatement(update);
    pStmnt.setString(1, orderId);               
    results = pStmnt.executeUpdate();

    if (results > 0) {
        added = true;
        getConn().commit(); //Added
        getConn().setAutoCommit(true); //Added
    }       
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: I'd be concerned about SQL Injection as it would pass order_id in with no checking.

Comment: True. In my case, the identifier was validated on the controller, and then passed to business logic, so there was no problems. Unfortunately, I couldn't get a better approach, as the tokenized query always returned / updated zero results

Comment: Added a finding I made about this... Hope it helps